# Naudio and FfftSharp program not working as expected

Tags: c#, audio, fft, naudio

I am trying to create a program in c# using [NAudio](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=a40af86cf1d3ff96JmltdHM9MTY5MzI2NzIwMCZpZ3VpZD0yMTZiODUyYi1hZGE1LTYwZDAtMTVlZC05NzAxYWM2MjYxYWQmaW5zaWQ9NTIwOA&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=216b852b-ada5-60d0-15ed-9701ac6261ad&psq=naudio&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL25hdWRpby9OQXVkaW8&ntb=1) and [FftSharp](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=fedc1c301f3b1db9JmltdHM9MTY5MzI2NzIwMCZpZ3VpZD0yMTZiODUyYi1hZGE1LTYwZDAtMTVlZC05NzAxYWM2MjYxYWQmaW5zaWQ9NTIwMg&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=216b852b-ada5-60d0-15ed-9701ac6261ad&psq=fftsharp&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9naXRodWIuY29tL3N3aGFyZGVuL0ZmdFNoYXJw&ntb=1) that will get the frequency with the highest power and Write it to the console. I followed [Plot Audio FFT](https://swharden.com/csdv/audio/fft/),and the code runs, but the code doesn't show the right frequency when fed with a sample.

```
using FftSharp;
using NAudio.Wave;
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //create new WaveInEvent
            WaveInEvent waveIn = new WaveInEvent()
            {
                BufferMilliseconds = 1000,
            };
            //Subscribe OnDataAvailable to DataAvailable
            waveIn.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
            //Start recording
            waveIn.StartRecording();
            Console.ReadKey();



        }
        static void OnDataAvailable(object? sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get an array of shorts representing amplitude
            double[] audioValues = GetAmplitude(e);
            //Clear the console
            Console.Clear();
            //Get power and generate frequency scale
            double[] power = GetFftPower(audioValues);
            double[] frequencyValues = FftSharp.FFT.FrequencyScale(power.Length, 8000);
            //Window audio to improve accuracy
            var window = new FftSharp.Windows.Hanning();
            double[] windowedAudio = window.Apply(power);
            //Get index of the highest power
            int maxIndex = 0;
            double max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < power.Length; i++)
            {
                if (windowedAudio[i] > max)
                {
                    max = windowedAudio[i];
                    maxIndex = i;
                }
            }
            //Write frequency and power to the console
            Console.WriteLine($"{frequencyValues[maxIndex]}: {windowedAudio[maxIndex]}");
            


        }
        static double[] GetAmplitude(WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            //Convert buffer bytes to shorts
            double[] audioValues = new double[e.BytesRecorded];
            
            for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i+=2)
            {
                
                audioValues[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(e.Buffer, i);
            }
            return audioValues;
        }
        static double[] GetFftPower(double[] audioValues)
        {
            //Convert shorts to Fft values
            double[] paddedAudio = FftSharp.Pad.ZeroPad(audioValues);
            System.Numerics.Complex[] spectrum = FftSharp.FFT.Forward(paddedAudio);
            double[] power = FftSharp.FFT.Power(spectrum);
            return power;
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the problem might be with bit converting, but I am not that experienced with programming with audio.

Comment: Can you show the sample code and explain why the result is not correct?

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand the question, but the code is in my answer. If you’re talking about output, I played A440 from my phone in a quiet room, and the frequency kept jumping around, with values spanning anywhere from 1000 to 3000 Hz. I also compared the values to an app called decibel x, and my program wasn’t even close.

Comment: You appear to applying a Hanning window to the Power Scale of the Fourier transform. Typically you would **1.** Get Audio Data **2.** Apply a Window to the Data **3.** Zero Pad the data **4.** Apply your Fourier Transform. You are almost there and you have all the correct pieces, I think they may just be in the wrong order.

Comment: I am also a little dubious of that `GetAmplitude` function, but can't test it myself. What I would recommend is to mock up a test audio file of maybe 4 known samples and see if you can print those 4 values out. Don't choose `1.0` but some [simple values like `±0.5`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388531/pythons-soundfile-soundfile-write-and-clipping/69391075#69391075) will give you an idea of how the data is structure

Comment: Okay, thanks! Sorry, I don’t have much experience with audio and I didn’t fully understand the docs on fftsharp. What’s wrong with the GetAmplitude function? It does the same thing as the tutorial at https://swharden.com/csdv/audio/fft/, just separate from the OnDataAvailable method, unless I’m mistaken. Also, I plan on running some values through fftsharp and just doing the DFT by hand and seeing if there is a difference. Thanks again!

Comment: @eop3 `GetAmplitude` is probably fine, but eye balling it I get the feeling that if there was a problem out side of simply the operation order, that's probably where I would start looking. In any case, trying some test values as sanity check should confirm if that function behaves properly. Your plan of writing your own DFT and comparing it to FftSharp is a great idea.

Comment: Alright, so I found out the problem... kind of. I had ai noise deduction enabled by default (I feel like an idiot right now). But now, a new problem has arisen. The fft returns 1/2 the frequency it is supposed to. I could just double the output frequency, but that feels like a hack more than a solution, and I have no idea why it would do that.